# XSLT space separated and adding an element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a query in the xml and xslt

The below is the Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<Employer>
    <Employees>
        <EmployeesDetails>van ind 26%</EmployeesDetails>
    </Employees>    
    <Employees>
        <EmployeesDetails>van ind</EmployeesDetails>
    </Employees>    
</Employer>
```

The above is my input file

the below is my output file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employer>
    <Employees>
        <Names>van</Names>
        <Location>ind</Location>                
        <Weather>26</Weather>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Names>van</Names>
        <Location>ind</Location>
        <Weather>100</Weather>
    </Employees>
</Employer>
```

How can I apply the below XSLT to the above XML input?

Comment: What have you tried so far? We'll happily help if you can show us where you got to.

Answer (score 1):

**I. This XSLT 2.0 transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <Employer>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Employer>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Employees">
  <xsl:variable name="vNames" select="tokenize(Names, ' ')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vLoc" select="tokenize(Location, ' ')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vWeather"
       select="tokenize(translate(Weather, '%', ' '), ' ')"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$vNames">
    <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()" as="xs:integer"/>
    <Employees>
      <Names><xsl:sequence select="."/></Names>
      <Location>
        <xsl:sequence select="(lower-case($vLoc[$vPos]), 'Unknown')[1]"/>
      </Location>
      <Weather>
        <xsl:sequence select="($vWeather[$vPos], 100)[1]"/>
      </Weather>
    </Employees>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Employer>
    <Employees>
        <Names>vel bel sel tel mel</Names>
        <Location>IND AUS ENG CAL JAP</Location>
        <Weather>26%</Weather>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Names>asd sadl asdsel tdddel dmdel</Names>
        <Location>IND AUS ENG CAL JAP</Location>
    </Employees>
</Employer>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Employer>
   <Employees>
      <Names>vel</Names>
      <Location>ind</Location>
      <Weather>26</Weather>
   </Employees>
   <Employees>
      <Names>bel</Names>
      <Location>aus</Location>
      <Weather>100</Weather>
   </Employees>
   <Employees>
      <Names>sel</Names>
      <Location>eng</Location>
      <Weather>100</Weather>
   </Employees>
   <Employees>
      <Names>tel</Names>
      <Location>cal</Location>
      <Weather>100</Weather>
   </Employees>
   <Employees>
      <Names>mel</Names>
      <Location>jap</Location>
      <Weather>100</Weather>
   </Employees>
      <Employees>
      <Names>asd</Names>
      <Location>ind</Location>
      <Weather>100</Weather>
   </Employees>
   <Employees>
      <Names>sadl</Names>
      <Location>aus</Location>
      <Weather>100</Weather>
   </Employees>
   <Employees>
      <Names>asdsel</Names>
      <Location>eng</Location>
      <Weather>100</Weather>
   </Employees>
   <Employees>
      <Names>tdddel</Names>
      <Location>cal</Location>
      <Weather>100</Weather>
   </Employees>
   <Employees>
      <Names>dmdel</Names>
      <Location>jap</Location>
      <Weather>100</Weather>
   </Employees>
</Employer>
```

**Do note**:

I have made the following reasonable assumptions:

1. You actually want `100`, not `100%`.
2. You want all `Employees` processed -- not only the first occurence of this element.

I also added a default value for any missing location, in case the number of provided locations is less than the number of the provided names.

---

**II. XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="ext my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <my:defaults>
  <L>Unknown</L>
  <W>100</W>
 </my:defaults>

 <xsl:variable name="vUpper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vLower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDefaults" select="document('')/*/my:defaults"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <Employer>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Employer>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Employees">
  <xsl:variable name="vrtfNames">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Names"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="vNames" select="ext:node-set($vrtfNames)/*"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vrtfLocs">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Location"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="vrtfWeather">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Weather"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vNames">
   <xsl:with-param name="pLocs" select="ext:node-set($vrtfLocs)/*"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="pWeather" select="ext:node-set($vrtfWeather)/*"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="s" priority="3">
  <xsl:param name="pLocs"/>
  <xsl:param name="pWeather"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
  <Employees>
   <Names><xsl:value-of select="."/></Names>
   <Location>
     <xsl:value-of select=
       "translate($pLocs[position() = $vPos]
                   | $vDefaults[not($pLocs[position() = $vPos])]/L,
                  $vUpper, $vLower)"/>
   </Location>
   <Weather>
     <xsl:value-of select=
       "$pWeather[position() = $vPos]
      | $vDefaults[not($pWeather[position() = $vPos])]/W"/>
   </Weather>
  </Employees>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Weather">
  <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="translate(., '%', ' ')"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Employees/*/text()" name="tokenize">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

  <xsl:variable name="vText" select="normalize-space($pText)"/>
  <xsl:if test="$vText">
   <s>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($vText, ' '), ' ')"/>
   </s>

   <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($vText, ' ')"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document (above), again the same wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Employer>
   <Employees>
      <Names>vel</Names>
      <Location>ind</Location>
      <Weather>26</Weather>
   </Employees>
   <Employees>
      <Names>bel</Names>
      <Location>aus</Location>
      <Weather>100</Weather>
   </Employees>
   <Employees>
      <Names>sel</Names>
      <Location>eng</Location>
      <Weather>100</Weather>
   </Employees>
   <Employees>
      <Names>tel</Names>
      <Location>cal</Location>
      <Weather>100</Weather>
   </Employees>
   <Employees>
      <Names>mel</Names>
      <Location>jap</Location>
      <Weather>100</Weather>
   </Employees>
   <Employees>
      <Names>asd</Names>
      <Location>ind</Location>
      <Weather>100</Weather>
   </Employees>
   <Employees>
      <Names>sadl</Names>
      <Location>aus</Location>
      <Weather>100</Weather>
   </Employees>
   <Employees>
      <Names>asdsel</Names>
      <Location>eng</Location>
      <Weather>100</Weather>
   </Employees>
   <Employees>
      <Names>tdddel</Names>
      <Location>cal</Location>
      <Weather>100</Weather>
   </Employees>
   <Employees>
      <Names>dmdel</Names>
      <Location>jap</Location>
      <Weather>100</Weather>
   </Employees>
</Employer>
```

**Do note**:

1. Essentially the same logic as in the XSLT 2.0 transformation is implemented.
2. As XPath 1.0 doesn't have a `tokenize` or `lower-case()` functions and there are is no notion of *sequence* in the XPath 1.0 data model, these are implemented (respectively) using a template for tokenization, using the `translate()` function to convert to lower case, and using an element that contains the defaults for weather and location.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague in some key areas. For instance, you seem to state that if a `<Employees>` nodeset *doesn't* have a `<weather>` node, it should get one with a value of 100%; that said, your expected output seems to apply that logic inconsistently. Your desired `<Location>` result node is transformed from uppercase to lowercase. Additionally, your output seems to completely disregard the second `<Employees>` node-set from the source XML.

Making some assumptions, here is an XSLT 1.0 solution that uses [EXSLT](http://www.exslt.org/). Should this not be what you want, please update your question to be more specific and I will try to accommodate.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  exclude-result-prefixes="exsl" 
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Employees">
    <xsl:variable name="vNames">
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="Names/text()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vLocations">
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="Location/text()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($vNames)/token">
      <xsl:with-param name="pLocation"
          select="exsl:node-set($vLocations)/token"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pWeather" select="Weather"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="token">
    <xsl:param name="pLocation"/>
    <xsl:param name="pWeather"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vPosition" select="position()"/>
    <Employees>
      <Names>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </Names>
      <Location>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate($pLocation[$vPosition],
            'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>
      </Location>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$pWeather != ''">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$pWeather"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <Weather>100%</Weather>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </Employees>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text,$delimiter)">
        <xsl:element name="token">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
          <xsl:with-param name="text"
              select="substring-after($text,$delimiter)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$text">
        <xsl:element name="token">
          <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied to this XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employer>
  <Employees>
    <Names>vel bel sel tel mel</Names>
    <Location>IND AUS ENG CAL JAP</Location>
    <Weather>26%</Weather>
  </Employees>
  <Employees>
    <Names>asd sadl asdsel tdddel dmdel</Names>
    <Location>IND AUS ENG CAL JAP</Location>
  </Employees>
</Employer>
```

**...the desired (?) result is produced:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employer>
  <Employees>
    <Names>vel</Names>
    <Location>ind</Location>
    <Weather>26%</Weather>
  </Employees>
  <Employees>
    <Names>bel</Names>
    <Location>aus</Location>
    <Weather>26%</Weather>
  </Employees>
  <Employees>
    <Names>sel</Names>
    <Location>eng</Location>
    <Weather>26%</Weather>
  </Employees>
  <Employees>
    <Names>tel</Names>
    <Location>cal</Location>
    <Weather>26%</Weather>
  </Employees>
  <Employees>
    <Names>mel</Names>
    <Location>jap</Location>
    <Weather>26%</Weather>
  </Employees>
  <Employees>
    <Names>asd</Names>
    <Location>ind</Location>
    <Weather>100%</Weather>
  </Employees>
  <Employees>
    <Names>sadl</Names>
    <Location>aus</Location>
    <Weather>100%</Weather>
  </Employees>
  <Employees>
    <Names>asdsel</Names>
    <Location>eng</Location>
    <Weather>100%</Weather>
  </Employees>
  <Employees>
    <Names>tdddel</Names>
    <Location>cal</Location>
    <Weather>100%</Weather>
  </Employees>
  <Employees>
    <Names>dmdel</Names>
    <Location>jap</Location>
    <Weather>100%</Weather>
  </Employees>
</Employer>
```

**Explanation:**

1. The first template - the [Identity Template](http://web.archive.org/web/20090525135108/http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html) - copies all elements and attributes as-is.
2. A second template, which matches `<Employee>` elements, runs a special `tokenize` template whose job it is to split your space-separate strings into result tree fragments. These fragments are saved into variables for convenience.
3. A third template matches all elements named `token`. These are produced by EXSLT, which converts result tree fragments into node-sets comprised of `<token>` elements. For each one of these, we pull the necessary element values to create `<Names>` and `<Location>`. This template also contains the logic necessary to determine which value is required for the `<weather>` element.

Comment: for Weather element if the input XML has the value for example <Weather>25%</Weather> the value has to display 25 in output, if there is no weather element in input XML by default it has to create weather node and the value will be 100.